# Python script to download sonarqube package only if there is any new available

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, sonarqube

I want to create a script which will automatically download the latest update if there any from this website https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ (community edition) .

Challenges

1. It should not download the file there is no latest update
2. After clicking on community edition on the above link it goes to a page where it has a link to "click here if it's not downloading"
3. It should only download the file if there is a new update available, if not available then it should exit the code and it can verify the current version in from currently installed version

Example

1. 7.9 is running on my machine and 8.9 is available on the internet then download
2. 8.9 is running on my machine and 8.9 is available on the internet then exit and don't download anything.

Comment: Have you created any Python script ? If yes, then please update the question with your code and then show what challenge you are facing in the script !!

Comment: @SouravAtta I didn't progress much as of now any suggestion would help.